# Smart Wizard - Multiples Only Resetting First Instance

Tags: jquery, smart-wizard

I have a form with multiple [Smart Wizards](http://techlaboratory.net/jquery-smartwizard) using incrementing UIDs for each. I want to restart the wizard to Step 1 when clicking the form Back or Reset buttons (external from the wizards). Step reset is only happening on the first instance of the Smart Wizard. I tried updating my JS to include all IDs which contain "smartwizard", but it is still only targeting the first one.

On the latest v5 [multiple demo](http://techlaboratory.net/projects/demo/jquery-smart-wizard/v5/multiple#step-1), the same / similar behavior can be viewed when advancing steps on both wizards and clicking cancel on the second one, triggering reset only on the first wizard.

Am I missing something with how and where the event handling is happening on the "reset" key in the Smart Wizard code (please see source links for reference)? I need guidance from this point, so any insight is appreciated...

**jQuery / JS File**

```
//FUNCTIONS FOR THE FORM BUTTONS
$('#back-button').on('click', function(event) {
    $('[id*="smartwizard"]').smartWizard('reset');
});

$('#reset-button').on('click', function(event) { // Reset form to initial state
    $('[id*="smartwizard"]').smartWizard('reset');
});
```

**SmartWizard**

```
      key: "reset",
  value: function reset() {
    // Reset all
    this._setURLHash('#');

    this._initOptions();

    this._initLoad();
  }
```

**HTML File**

```
//FORM SNIPPET
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="process" id="process1">
                                        <div id="smartwizard">
                                            <ul class="nav">
                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#step-1">
                                                        <strong>Step 1</strong> <h4>Introduction</h4>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>

                                            <div class="tab-content">
                                                <div id="step-1" class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="step-1">
                                                    <h3>Step 1 Content</h3>
                                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="step-2" class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="step-2">
                                                    <h3>Step 2 Content</h3>
                                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>


                                <ul>
                                    <li class="process" id="process2">
                                        <div id="smartwizard2">
                                            <ul class="nav">
                                                <li class="nav-item">
                                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#step-1">
                                                        <strong>Step 1</strong> <h4>Introduction</h4>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>

                                            <div class="tab-content">
                                                <div id="step-1" class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="step-1">
                                                    <h3>Step 1 Content</h3>
                                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                                                </div>
                                                <div id="step-2" class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="step-2">
                                                    <h3>Step 2 Content</h3>
                                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button id="back-button" type="button">BACK</button>
        <button id="reset-button" type="reset">RESET</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, I found some inspiration for how to iterate through all of the Smart Wizards using [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) with an array of the IDs.

I still believe the code could be refactored for simplicity to encompass all IDs containing "smartwizard", but this solved my issue with both external buttons and I only need to maintain the array values in one place as more Smart Wizards are added to the page.

```
var wizard = ["smartwizard", "smartwizard2"];

$('#back-button').on('click', function(event) { // Undo last selection and reset steps
    $.each(wizard, function(i, val) {
        $("#" + val).smartWizard('reset');
    });
});


$('#reset-button').on('click', function(event) { // Reset steps to initial state
    $.each(wizard, function( i, val ) {
        $("#" + val).smartWizard('reset');
    });
});
```